# Send plain text email using EmailModel?

Tags: plugin-development, emails

I currently have a plugin that's successfully sending email using `EmailModel()`. The problem is: it's sending a multi-part email with HTML and plain text components. For this particular email, it would be best if I could just send the plain text portion.

Is there a way to disable the HTML segment when sending via `EmailModel()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently not.  If Craft sees that there isn't anything specified for the [htmlBody](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/EmailModel#htmlBody-detail) property of [EmailModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/EmailModel) will run the [body](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/EmailModel#body-detail) property though Markdown and set that to htmlBody.

Comment: Ok, good to know. I've managed to get a minimal version of the HTML working as expected, so it probably won't be too bad. Thanks for the confirmation, though!

Comment: I see this is still the case. It's actually a real pain not being able to send plain text emails. I'm having to roll back to php mail() to get the job done for my purpose.

Comment: @JamesNZ You should consider thumbs-upping/leave a comment here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1107